# Starting with IntelliJ - Dependency manager like in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, intellij-plugin

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA and I was looking for some plugin that allows me an easy dependency management like this (look at the picture below) to easily add/remove dependencies. I have not found anything at all. Maybe someone of you know about any plugin.

Image Link: [Eclipse pom.xml dependency manager](https://postimg.org/image/iwlavczm5/)

It is really important for me since I add/remove dependencies a lot and it really takes a lot of time to copy it from the internet, checking if it's the latest version and etc.

Comment: To be honest it's just as quick and easy to edit the pom.xml by hand... use `Alt-Insert` inside the `<dependencies>` list to search.

Comment: Note that referring to your readership as "stuck-up programmers" is not a good approach - please keep a positive and generous frame of mind when posting here. The downvote system is just a communication mechanism, and it is right that people use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such view in IDEA.

You can add a dependency like so: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-maven-dependencies.html

> Open the desired pom.xml file for editing.
>   With the editor tab having the focus, choose Code | Generate on the main menu, or press Alt+Insert, and choose Dependency from the Generate pop-up window.

Viewing all dependencies as a diagram is described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-maven-dependencies.html

> Do one of the following:
>
> In the Maven Projects tool window, right-click the desired sub project or a package, and choose Show Dependencies, or Show Dependencies Popup.
>
> Right-click pom.xml in the editor, and choose Dependencies | Show Dependencies /Show Dependencies popup.

I agree that the Eclipse way looks nicer.
You can file a feature request here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Let me know if you have done so. I'll vote for it.

Comment: Wow amazing! thanks a lot!  The that's the exact thing i was looking for, also just inserting a dependency template and then dynamicaly searching inside the editor. Wow! thank you! :) This helped me a lot no more copypasta :D